# MS Access: How to Supply Parameters to a Query-Based Subform Control

Tags: ms-access, vba

Given the following setup, how do you supply parameters to the query?:

- FormA contains SubformA.
- SubformA uses QueryA, a saved query, as its SourceObject.
- QueryA uses a PARAMETERS declaration
- FormA contains Controls that supply the parameters to QueryA.

If FormA's Controls have the same name as QueryA's parameters, this generally works.  The exception is when the form loads, at which time Access prompts the user for QueryA's parameters.  I am trying to get around this by leaving SubformA's SourceObject blank in Design View and defining the SourceObject in FormA's Form_Load event.  I am setting the values of FormA's controls and then setting SubformA's SourceObject.  However, Access is still prompting for the parameters. My next thought was to get a reference to QueryA as a QueryDef and define the QueryDef's parameters, but there doesn't appear to be a way to assign the QueryDef as SubformA's SourceObject.  Any thoughts on how to obtain the objective of not prompting the user for the parameters on form load?

Comment: Why are you not using link child and master fields rather than parameters? It should make these problems go away.

Comment: In this case FormA is unbound, so there is nothing to link to.  In case more detail is useful, FormA contains a ListBox (that uses a SQL statement as its RowSource) and two TextBox date fields.  The ListBox selection(s) are used to filter QueryA's results with something along the line of "WHERE table_field IN FormAListBoxSelections."  The dates are also used to filter QueryA's results (WHERE a_date BETWEEN FormA("start_date") AND FormA("end_date").  QueryA itself is a conglomerate of several other queries that join several tables.

Comment: It does not matter that form a is unbound, only that it contains controls, but I can see it will not suit in this case. Is there a business rule that says the form must be filtered when it is loaded? Is there any objection to presenting the user with a form to choose criteria and a completely full or completely empty list? If this is not possible, how do you feel about offering the user their previous selection?

Comment: There is no business rule requiring that the form be populated on load and there is no problem with presenting an empty list.  This is why I tried to set the SourceObject on Form_Load. That said, your comment led me to try leaving the SourceObject empty in Design View and setting it when the Form's query/filter button is clicked.  This has the same behavior - As soon as the SourceObject is set the query executes and it does *not* read its parameters from the form controls.  However, every time the query is executed after that, it *does* read its parameters from the form controls.

Comment: Have you defined the controls as parameters in the Recordsource of the subform?

Comment: @Adam - if you are still having this issue the following link may help http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=200250

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the controls as parameters in the Recordsource of the subform? I'm not sure it would work even then, since I think subforms load before the main form, and that they are requeried a second time after loading.

I'd suggest having an empty recordsource in the subform, and set the Recordsource SQL when you apply the filter. I wouldn't define any parameters and I would use no references to form controls in the Recordsource SQL at all.

If you are somehow concerned about SQL injection and think you must use parameters, likely your concerns are overblown, particularly if none of the filter controls allow free text.

Comment: I was avoiding changing from saved Queries because of the increased difficulty of maintaining the SQL in VBA, but I finally caved & started going the direction you have suggested. What do you set the subform SourceObject to? If the SourceObject is the saved Query object (I haven't deleted it yet) & I change the RecordSource when the button is clicked, it works fine, but a blank SourceObject just yields an empty control. I attempted creating an empty query (e.g., SELECT NULL AS field1, NULL AS field2), using that as a SourceObject and then setting the RecordSource, but the data doesn't display.

Comment: I found one approach to this is to create a new QueryDef in the DB using CurrentDB().CreateQueryDef(tempQueryName, tempQuerySQL), using the desired query for tempQuerySQL. Then set the subform SourceObject to "Queries.tempQueryName."  Of course, once *tempQueryName* is created, it doesn't have to be created again.  Is there an alternative method of accomplishing this that you would recommend?  If not, I'm debating whether it is better to leave *tempQueryName* in the DB or to delete it when the form is closed.  Any suggestion here?

Comment: I assumed you were using an actual subform as the SourceObject, as opposed to a saved query. I find using the latter to not be something that is useful very often. That is, I'd just create a subform so I'd then have all the flexibility I needed in setting its recordsource.